# undefined variable in matlab for a strcture

Tags: matlab, function, variables, structure

this is kind of lame but i am not able to remove this error. i have a function where i supply the name of a component which is an element inside the structure add_strcut.

so add_strcut has data_a , data_b etc.

and data_a has the field 'ode'. and again 'ode' has 'input'.

```
function bus_creator(component_name)
if (isfield(add_strcut.(component_name),'ode')==1)
    for loop_out=1:length(add_strcut.(component_name).ode.input)
        for loop_in=1:length(fieldnames(add_strcut.(component_name).ode.input{loop_out,2}))
        struct_name=add_strcut.(component_name).ode.input{loop_out,2}.(char(fieldnames(add_strcut.(component_name).ode.input{loop_in,2})));
        bus_creator_record(struct_name);
        end
    end
end
```

end

ofcourse here while calling the function i supply the component name as 'data_a'. but the second line throws me error.

the error is undefuned variable "add_strcut" or class  "add_strcut.data_a"

even though when i use F9 to check the value it shows me fine but when i call this function it throws me this error

**update**

```
function bus_creator(main_component,component_name)
    if (isfield(main_component.(component_name),'ode')==1)
        for loop_out=1:length(main_component.(component_name).ode.input)
            for loop_in=1:length(fieldnames(main_component.(component_name).ode.input{loop_out,2}))
            struct_name=main_component.(component_name).ode.input{loop_out,2}.(char(fieldnames(main_component.(component_name).ode.input{loop_in,2})));
            bus_creator_record(struct_name);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

this is the updated function. now i will supply main_component='add_strcut' but now to access it as  a variable i need to put main_component inside brackets but if i do that then it throws me error 
at `(main_component).(component_name)`

it shows the dot in between in red and error is unexpected matlab operator

Comment: Unless declared global a variable defined outside of a function cannot be seen outside the function scope. So the solution is to pass `add_strcut` to the function (instead of only `component_name`). Another solution is to remove all calls to `add_strcut` and only call `component_name`.

Comment: you never pass `add_strcut` variable to the function `bus_creator` ... so sure it is not defined in its scope ...

Comment: Brackets are used to reference fields in structures dynamically (see [this](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html)) ... For instance, if `component_name`is the string `toto`, then this line checks that  `main_component.toto.ode` exists.

Comment: unexpected matlab operator. the dot is red in color showing its not a right syntax

Comment: this line doesn'T work main_component.(component_name) because it thinks main_component is actually the name of the structure and not a variable which has string in it

Comment: ok it works now...i just had to pass the main_component as G11 instead of  the as a character 'G11'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when passing the main structure don't use any quotes. just pass the structure name straight to the function without using ''.